# Show the data type of elements inside the array and convert it to Integer. Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

so i'm struggling with one of the questions in my assignment. We are given txt file containing a few hundred elements and we need to show the data type of elements inside the array bike (the text file) and convert it to Integer.

I have tried

```py
print(type(bike))
bike.astype(int)
```

and get

```py
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array([ 985,  801, 1349, 1562, 1600, 1606, 1510,  959,  822, 1321, 1263,
       1162, 1406, 1421, 1248, 1204, 1000,  683, 1650, 1927, 1543,  981,
        986, 1416, 1985,  506,  431, 1167, 1098, 1096, 1501, 1360, 1526,
       1550, 1708, 1005, 1623, 1712, 1530, 1605, 1538, 1746, 1472, 1589,
       1913, 1815, 2115, 2475, 2927, 1635, 1812, 1107, 1450, 1917, 1807,
       1461, 1969, 2402, 1446, 1851, 2134, 1685, 1944, 2077,  605, 1872,
       2133, 1891,  623, 1977, 2132, 2417, 2046, 2056, 2192, 2744, 3239,
       311, ...])
```

*The dots above just show theres a lot more data*

I was expecting what I tried, to return 'Int' or something similar after running `bike.astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.dtype` attribute of numpy arrays

```
bike.dtype
```

result (after conversion to integers)

```
dtype('int64')
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I now however have encountered another error. When i try ```dec_2011 = bike[count_days(2011, 12, 0)-1]``` ```dec_2011[3] = 10000``` (count days was a function supplied to us) I get ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-4d9f48ba717e> in <module>
----> 1 dec_2011[3] = 10000

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment``` and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to take the contents within your text file and convert them to their integer values you can use the ord() function and if you wish to get get their data types you can use type() function.

The ord() function returns the number representing the unicode code of a specified character.

example code:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
contents = f.read()
dtype_and_int_values = [[type(item), ord(item)] for item in contents]
print(dtype_and_int_values)
```